# JBoss strucked at Remoting

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

I am new to JBoss deployment. I am using Java 32 bit, Unix, Jboss 6 environment. While starting my application shell file X.sh, Jboss struck at Remote service. I have spent lot of time but didn't get any clue to resolve. Please find the error below.

```
14:34:13,100 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized

14:34:24,603 INFO  [AbstractServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native Server 3.4.1.GA

14:34:25,157 INFO  [JSFImplManagementDeployer] Initialized 3 JSF configurations: [Mojarra-1.2, MyFaces-2.0, Mojarra-2.0] 

14:34:32,683 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal

14:34:37,911 INFO  [mbean] Sleeping for 600 seconds

14:34:38,214 WARNING [FileConfigurationParser] AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal

14:34:38,425 INFO  [JMXConnector] starting JMXConnector on host 0.0.0.0:1090

14:34:38,560 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail

14:34:39,623 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] live server is starting..

14:34:39,705 INFO  [JournalStorageManager] Using NIO Journal

14:34:39,730 WARNING [HornetQServerImpl] Security risk! It has been detected that the cluster admin user and password have not been changed from the installation default. Please see the HornetQ user guide, cluster chapter, for instructions on how to do this.

14:34:40,970 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.1.Final-r2319 0.0.0.0:5455 for CORE protocol

14:34:40,971 INFO  [NettyAcceptor] Started Netty Acceptor version 3.2.1.Final-r2319 0.0.0.0:5445 for CORE protocol

14:34:40,975 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] HornetQ Server version 2.1.2.Final (Colmeia, 120) started

14:34:41,040 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://esaxh036.hyd.lab.vignette.com:8083/

14:34:41,271 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32010 JBossTS Recovery Service (tag: JBOSSTS_4_14_0_Final) - JBoss Inc.

14:34:41,281 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12324 Start RecoveryActivators

14:34:41,301 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12296 ExpiredEntryMonitor running at Thu, 30 Oct 2014 14:34:41

14:34:41,323 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12332 Failed to establish connection to server

14:34:41,348 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12304 Removing old transaction status manager item 0:ffff0a601a3e:126a:5451fbf6:8

14:34:41,390 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12310 Recovery manager listening on endpoint 0.0.0.0:4712

14:34:41,390 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12344 RecoveryManagerImple is ready on port 4712

14:34:41,391 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32013 Starting transaction recovery manager

14:34:41,402 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12163 Starting service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port 4713

14:34:41,403 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12337 TransactionStatusManagerItem host: 0.0.0.0 port: 4713

14:34:41,425 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12170 TransactionStatusManager started on port 4713 and host 0.0.0.0 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService

14:34:41,480 INFO  [jbossatx] ARJUNA-32017 JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag: JBOSSTS_4_14_0_Final) - JBoss Inc.

14:34:41,549 INFO  [arjuna] ARJUNA-12202 registering bean jboss.jta:type=ObjectStore.

14:34:41,764 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /home/IWSTU/JBOSS/jboss-6.0.0.Final/bin/native/lib

14:34:41,922 INFO  [ModClusterService] Initializing mod_cluster 1.1.0.Final

14:34:41,935 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker

14:34:42,364 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/home/IWSTU/JBOSS/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XDomain/deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml

14:34:42,382 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/home/IWSTU/JBOSS/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XDomain/deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml

14:34:42,395 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/home/IWSTU/JBOSS/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XDomain/deploy/jms-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml

14:34:42,410 INFO  [HornetQResourceAdapter] HornetQ resource adaptor started

14:34:42,421 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/home/IWSTU/JBOSS/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XDomain/deploy/mail-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml

14:34:42,439 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfs:/home/IWSTU/JBOSS/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/XDomain/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml

14:34:42,544 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: Thread-7

14:34:42,578 INFO  [SchedulerSignalerImpl] Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl

14:34:42,579 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.8.3 created.

14:34:42,582 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.

14:34:42,585 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v1.8.3) 'JBossQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

14:34:42,585 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'JBossQuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally opened InputStream.

14:34:42,586 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.8.3

14:34:42,586 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler JBossQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.

14:34:43,229 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound 
ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'

14:34:43,422 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/juddi

14:34:43,488 INFO  [RegistryServlet] Loading jUDDI configuration.

14:34:43,494 INFO  [RegistryServlet] Resources loaded from: /WEB-INF/juddi.properties

14:34:43,494 INFO  [RegistryServlet] Initializing jUDDI components.

14:34:43,688 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'

14:34:43,738 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=OracleDS' to JNDI name 'java:OracleDS'

14:34:43,926 INFO  [xnio] XNIO Version 2.1.0.CR2

14:34:43,937 INFO  [nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 2.1.0.CR2

**14:34:44,170 INFO  [remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.1.0.Beta2** (Strucked here)

14:44:37,912 INFO  [TicketMap] Start:

14:44:37,913 INFO  [TicketMap] Complete:

14:44:37,930 INFO  [mbean] Sleeping for 600 seconds

14:54:37,932 INFO  [TicketMap] Start:

14:54:37,932 INFO  [TicketMap] Complete:

14:54:37,944 INFO  [mbean] Sleeping for 600 seconds
```

Comment: What does "strucked" mean?

Comment: Hi, Strucked means -- After the step "[remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.1.0.Beta2 ", it is going to loop 600 sec sleep. after 5 trails, JBoss is halting. I don't know what exactly it is expecting ? Does any configuration is missing? In general, after this remote step, server should up and running ..